# BST: When inserting a node into a red-black tree, in which direction are the nodes rotated?

Tags: binary-search-tree, computer-science

I am learning about binary search trees, and I am trying to wrap my head around red-black trees at the moment. I don't understand the direction of rotation for red-black trees: If a node is inserted to the left of a parent (which I assume would have no children), would it be rotated to right? Or in a more general sense, whenever a node is inserted to the right or left of parent with no children, would the node and parent be rotated to the opposite direction?

Comment: What does the algorithm tell you? Did you work through it on paper? What is the result?

Comment: @LutzHorn There's no an algorithm or anything, this is just a conceptual question. If it helps, this came up as a result of trying to find out how to properly balance a red-black tree, so maybe how they would be rotated to ensure proper balance?